# SVG with multiple path and g tags

Tags: javascript, css, svg

i have created below function and variable as below to add a svg in class.(c-contact-address).

where i can add single path successfully but i need multiple paths and g tags if possible in same svg.

can someone please help me out ?

```
 const contactUsSvg = () => {
  const contactUs = SVG();
  contactUs.addClass("c-contact-address").viewbox(0, 0, 1513.1, 619.1);

  contactUs.svg(
    '<path class="c-contact-address-path" d="M1.5 157.7c37.3-43.3 99-64.1 154.9-52S259.9 162.1 275.9        217c7.2 24.7 8.1 52.1-2.9 75.3-11.1 23.2-35.9 40.7-61.4 38.2-14.8-1.4-30.9-17.2-22.2-29.2 2.4-3.3 6.1-5.3 9.8-7 13.2-5.8 28.2-8 42.2-4.7 40.5 9.6 56.8 56.7 74.7 94.3 42.4 89 127.7 152.7 221 184.7 108.8 37.2 243.1 42 355.5 20.7 61.7-11.7 139.8-20.2 185.2-67 27.9-28.8 72.9-109.6 70.9-197.4" fill="none" stroke="#dde5ed" stroke-width="3.022" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" style="stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-dasharray: none;"></path>'
  );``
```

----->Above code is working for single path but how can i add multiple paths in same  contactUs.svg()

----->Above code is working for single path but how can i add multiple paths in same  contactUs.svg()

Comment: OK, what's the problem though? Just add multiple paths wrapped in a <g> </g> or <> </>

Comment: I presume ``SVG()`` comes from the **svg.js** library you loaded. Then RTFM - **_read the fine manual_**, and look for ``SVG().addTo('#drawing')`` and the like statements. See: https://svgjs.dev/